# What do you call a made up name?

Tags: morphology

Many businesses create new words for themselves or their products. Is there a term for these words? For example, in the movie, "Bladerunner," androids are called, "Replicants." So the word Replica + the suffix -ant.

Comment: *Coinage*. If it begins to enter common parlance, *neologism*.

Comment: Neologism: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/neologism

Comment: As well as *neologism* which tends to be a word created for more permanent use, there is also " nonce-word" which the OED describes as *a word apparently used only on one specific occasion or in one specific text or writer's works.* and gives the example: 1884   N.E.D. at "***Agreemony***:   *A nonce-word, probably intended to suggest acrimony.*"